# How to load all data from firebase, before running UITableView functions in xcode/swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to load data from my firestore database, so that when my Table View Controller loads, it will present data that is currently stored in the database. 
To do this I call a function in ViewDidLoad() that populates an array of values retrieved from the database. However, when I run my code, I am getting an index out of bounds error in my cellForRowAt table View function. I assume that the code to set up the view is running before the actual array is getting populated. So there are no values in the array to set up the table. The data is being accessed because I am able to print the data to the console. Also when I print out my array.count it is returning 0. So I know the data is not getting put in the array.

I have searched for solutions but none are working for me. I have found solutions that suggest using GroupDispatch asynch functions to have it wait for the retrieval of my data. None of this seems to be working for me. Here is the code that I am trying.

```
    var didfinishloading = false{
    didSet{
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    initialGet()
    //populateDatabase()
}


func initialGet(){
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    dispatchGroup.enter()

    db.collection("PlayerStats").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {

        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            let stats = PlayerStats(name:document.data()["name"] as! String, points: document.data()["points"] as! Int, assists: document.data()["assists"] as! Int, rebounds: document.data()["rebounds"] as! Int, image: document.data()["image"] as! String)
            self.playerArray.append(stats)
            dispatchGroup.leave()

            }
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main){
            self.didfinishloading = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use the didFinishLoading variable to tell when all the data has been retrieved, and then I want it to reload the data when it is set to true.

If anyone could provide help, or point me in the right direction with this?

Comment: The array that feeds your tableview can be initialized to empty [], when the view is loaded it uses this empty array. load the data at the end (of the data or page if paged) assign it to the array used by tableview and reload tableview. There is no way out of bound happens in this process.

Comment: So much forced unwrapping! I would clean all of that up. Just because the data exists in the database doesn't guarantee that it will come through intact on the client. Network and machine errors are real. If anything ever hiccups, your entire app will crash. What you should do is safeguard against hiccups so they're not added to the table. I would also make use of `get()` on document fields (built into the FIrestore API) when extracting data properties, instead of converting them to data and then accessing raw values.

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing `DispatchGroup`. In your case you don't need it at all.

And reload the table view directly inside the closure.

```
func initialGet(){

    db.collection("PlayerStats").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                let stats = PlayerStats(name:data["name"] as! String, 
                                        points: data["points"] as! Int, 
                                        assists: data["assists"] as! Int, 
                                        rebounds: data["rebounds"] as! Int, 
                                        image: data["image"] as! String)
                self.playerArray.append(stats)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you still get an out-of-bounds exception then there's something wrong with your table view datasource methods

Comment: Okay, it still doesn't work it is still saying that my array is empty and I am stiil getting the index out of range error in my cellForRowAt method

Comment: As I said the error is related to the code in `cellForRow` or (more likely) in`numberOfRows`

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.playerArray = [PlayerStats]()

    initialGet()
    //populateDatabase()
}

func initialGet(){
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    dispatchGroup.enter()

    db.collection("PlayerStats").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {

        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            let stats = PlayerStats(name:document.data()["name"] as! String, points: document.data()["points"] as! Int, assists: document.data()["assists"] as! Int, rebounds: document.data()["rebounds"] as! Int, image: document.data()["image"] as! String)
            self.playerArray.append(stats)
            dispatchGroup.leave()

            }

    }
    }
    dispatchGroup.wait()
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
       self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Make sure your playerArray is initialized and empty in viewDidLoad if you didn't instantiate it as an empty instance variable. Then move the dispatchGroup.notify out of the db.collection call. You can play around with the wait function maybe add on a timeout if you'd like. You don't need the didFinish check.